# Darling is not installing no matter what ... [ elementary OS 6 Odin ]

Tags: software-installation, release-odin

I am new to here so forgive me if I ask stupid question. I am coming from macOS and would like to give "darling" a try. Unfortunately, no matter what I try to do, there is always some issue breaking the installation process.

The latest message is:

```
darling-dkms can not access headers at kernel source
```

( btw: I don't see build nor source in the given location )

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing the application from source, you may need to first install the kernel headers, which will then let you compile against them. You can do this by opening Terminal and typing this:

```
sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

You may also need some additional packages installed that can be referenced by the application. Based on [this AskUbuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1360698/1222991), these are required:

```
sudo apt install cmake clang bison flex libfuse-dev libudev-dev pkg-config libc6-dev-i386 \
     linux-headers-generic gcc-multilib libcairo2-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libtiff5-dev \
     libfreetype6-dev git libelf-dev libxml2-dev libegl1-mesa-dev libfontconfig1-dev libbsd-dev \
     libxrandr-dev libxcursor-dev libgif-dev libavutil-dev libpulse-dev libavformat-dev libavcodec-dev \
     libavresample-dev libdbus-1-dev libxkbfile-dev libssl-dev
```

Once installed, you should be able to install the application

Comment: Thank you for prompt response :)

Comment: All looked much more appealing and darling-dkms installation went very far and then:

Comment: Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.11.0-40-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/darling-mach/0.1/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package darling-dkms (--configure):
 installed darling-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 darling-dkms
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: There may be some additional dependencies. I've updated the answer based on a solution from AskUbuntu.